# Comparing 'N' Similar Cloned Records in same table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

We use a cloning application which clones a single record in a table to 'N' numbers of records into the same table. It only changes the primary key and keep a unique for every cloned record but all other data will be same for all 'N' records.

This is what I want to achieve in SQL Server: I want to compare all the N records and make sure they are correctly cloned (that means I need to ensure all 'N' records have same data).

Please let me know if anyone has a clue how to do this in SQL Server. For just two records I can do with 'except statement' but here there are 95 cloned records...

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. If you're going to compare a 'cloned' record to a parent record you will need a parent_id.

That way you could do something like this:

```
select 
    *
from
    [table] as [p]
inner join
    [table] as [c]
 on [p].primary_key = [c].parent_key
where
    [p].field1 != [c].field1
 or [p].field2 != [c].field2
```

Comment: Hi Michael , here parent key and cloned key are different and also i need to compare all the 95 clones.  Thanks Run..

Comment: @user1542758, I agree that [p].primary_key != [c].primary_key. You'll need an additional field that stores the value of the parent_key, that is the primary_key of whichever record the 'clone' is derived.

Comment: There is no additional field for parent record. parent and clones reside in the same table.

Comment: In my example [table] ( the table where original records and clones reside ) is referenced twice. It is the same table. You need to add an additional field 'parent_key' which will be a foreign key to the primary id of the original record.